# Conditioning on initial condition in stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following stochastic differential equation
$$
\mathrm d X_t = b(X_t) \, \mathrm d t + \mathrm d W_t,  
\qquad X_0 = \xi, \qquad \xi \sim \mu
$$
where $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion on $\mathbb R$ and $\mu \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ is a given probability distribution on $\mathbb R$ such that $\xi$ has finite second moment.
Assume that $b$ is smooth and globally Lipschitz continuous,
so that a unique strong solution exists,
with law denoted by $\mathbb P_{\mu}$ on the space of continuous functions $C([0, \infty))$.
Suppose that $\mathcal F$ is a functional on $C([0, \infty))$ that is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $C([0, \infty))$ and integrable with respect to $\mathbb P_{\mu}$.
I would like to justify rigorously that
$$
\mathbb E_{\mu}[\mathcal F] = \int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb E_{\delta_x}[\mathcal F] \, \mu(\mathrm d x),
$$
where $\mathbb E_{\delta_x}$ is the expectation under $\mathbb P_{\delta_x}$, which itself is the law of the solution over path space with the deterministic initial condition $X_0 = x$.
What is the simplest approach to this end? It seems that the result follows from Corollary 2.2 in the [classical paper](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/gubinelli/stochastic-analysis-ss22/Yamada_and_Watanabe_-_1971_-_On_the_uniqueness_of_solutions_of_stochastic_diffe.pdf) by Yamada and Watanabe, but I am wondering whether there is a simpler answer.

- In particular, does this follow evidently from the proofs of existence of a weak solution, with which I am not familiar?
- I think the question may be related to showing that $(x, A) \mapsto \mathbb P_{\delta_x}(A)$ is a regular conditional probability of $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with initial condition $\xi \sim \mu$ given $X_0 = x$, but not sure this helps.

Comment: This question had already been asked (and answered) apparently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614302/initial-distribution-of-stochastic-differential-equations?rq=1. There is also a proof in this paper by Figalli (Lemma 2.4, https://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1292/martsol.pdf) but it is a bit convoluted.

Comment: @Titti : Yes, I saw that question. I was just hoping for a more straightforward answer, not via the martingale problem. Many thanks for the reference to Figalli's paper!